# PHP Loop for x = 1to 20

Tags: php

I am looking for a way to simplify this.

```
    $token2h=substr(str_shuffle("0p23456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNoPQRSZUVWXYZ"), 0, 20);
    $token3h=substr(str_shuffle("0p23456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNoPQRSZUVWXYZ"), 0, 20);
    $token4h=substr(str_shuffle("0p23456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNoPQRSZUVWXYZ"), 0, 20);
    $token5h=substr(str_shuffle("0p23456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNoPQRSZUVWXYZ"), 0, 20);
    $token6h=substr(str_shuffle("0p23456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNoPQRSZUVWXYZ"), 0, 20);
    $token7h=substr(str_shuffle("0p23456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNoPQRSZUVWXYZ"), 0, 20);
    $token8h=substr(str_shuffle("0p23456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNoPQRSZUVWXYZ"), 0, 20);
    $token9h=substr(str_shuffle("0p23456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNoPQRSZUVWXYZ"), 0, 20);
    $token10h=substr(str_shuffle("0p23456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNoPQRSZUVWXYZ"), 0, 20);
    $token11h=substr(str_shuffle("0p23456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNoPQRSZUVWXYZ"), 0, 20);
    $token12h=substr(str_shuffle("0p23456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNoPQRSZUVWXYZ"), 0, 20);
    $token13h=substr(str_shuffle("0p23456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNoPQRSZUVWXYZ"), 0, 20);
    $token14h=substr(str_shuffle("0p23456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNoPQRSZUVWXYZ"), 0, 20);
    $token15h=substr(str_shuffle("0p23456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNoPQRSZUVWXYZ"), 0, 20);
    $token16h=substr(str_shuffle("0p23456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNoPQRSZUVWXYZ"), 0, 20);
    $token17h=substr(str_shuffle("0p23456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNoPQRSZUVWXYZ"), 0, 20);
    $token18h=substr(str_shuffle("0p23456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNoPQRSZUVWXYZ"), 0, 20);
    $token19h=substr(str_shuffle("0p23456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNoPQRSZUVWXYZ"), 0, 20);
    $token20h=substr(str_shuffle("0p23456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNoPQRSZUVWXYZ"), 0, 20);
```

I have tried various ways to make a loop but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: This is exactly what [arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) are for.

Answer (score 1):

You can either make an **array of tokens** or make the **token variables** on the fly using [range()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) and [foreach()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php),

```
<?php
$range = range(2,20);

# make an array for tokens using rnage
foreach($range as $k){
    $tokens["token{$k}h"] = substr(str_shuffle("0p23456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNoPQRSZUVWXYZ"), 0, 20);
}

# make token variables using range
foreach($range as $k){
    ${"token{$k}h"} = substr(str_shuffle("0p23456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNoPQRSZUVWXYZ"), 0, 20);
}
```

?>

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/R2LRF

Comment: @MartyMcFly glad it helps you somehow. By the way, don't forget to accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think way is on dynamic variable names:

```
<?php
for ($i= 2; $i <= 20; $i++) 
{ 
    ${'token'. $i .'h'} = substr(str_shuffle("0p23456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNoPQRSZUVWXYZ"), 0, 20);
}  
?>
```